# How to get model instance in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to pass a common variable in every model in CodeIgniter. I am searching for `CI_Model instance` like `get_instance()` that is for `CI_Controller`.

I am trying like this from my controller:

```
$ci_model = an_ci_model_instance();
$config['testvar'] = "Test Value";
$this->load->model($ci_model, '', $config);
```

And I want to access the testvar variable from any model. I am sorry if the question is some kind of ambiguous.

Comment: Did you get any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a new file in `application/core/MY_Model.php`:

```
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {
     public $somevar = 'foobar';
}
```

then in every model in `application/models` do:

```
class Some_model extends MY_Model {
    function dosomething() {
        echo $this->somevar;
    }
}
```

thus:

```
$this->load->model('some_model');
$this->some_model->dosomething(); // prints 'foobar'
```

---

The 2nd parameter of the model loading is to just change the name you access it with and the 3rd is only for db config.

You can also do this same method and just extend `CI_Controller` with a `MY_Controller` and the var will also be accessible to all models without extending a `MY_Model` however in such a case your controllers will have to extend `MY_Controller`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you get any error? On when PHP_ERROR on at time ?

Try this

CI_Base::get_instance();